# How to disable selected list values in subsequent lists?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table with one column which has the list of values .The list is same in all the rows.

Now when user selects the value for first row, I want to disable it for all the rows, and when user select second value in second row, that value should be disabled in all upcoming rows and so on.So that user don't have the option to choose one value for more than one column.

I could disable the first selected value in all the columns but dont know how to do it for all the rows.

**DB Table**

```
sqlite> select * from outdoor_games;
games
 ----------
Badminton
Football
Basketball
Golf
```

**Code**

```
<?php
$db =  new PDO("sqlite:c:/sqlite/games.db");  
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query_game = $db->prepare("select distinct games as di from outdoor_games;");
$query_game->execute();
$data = $query_game->fetchAll(); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
 </head>
 <body>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"  method="post">
    <TABLE id="STable" width="350px" border="1">
            <tr>    <th bgcolor="WHITESMOKE">Game Id </th>  </tr>
            <TR>    <td><select name= "Game_id[]" class='Game'/> <option value="">Games</option>
                        <?php foreach ($data as $row){echo '<option value="' . $row['di'] . '">' . $row ['di'] . '</option>';} ?>
                    </select></td>
            </TR>
    </TABLE></br> 
    <label>No. of games <input type= "text" id="s_cnt" name= "d_Count"></label>
    <button type="button" class='loadgames' >Load Games</button>
    <input type="submit" name ="add_SP" value ="Add Student Info" style="float: right;" /> </br> </br>
    <input type="submit" name ="exit" value ="EXIT"  />
</form>
<script>  

    $('.Game').on('click', function()
    {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $('.Game').not(this).find('option[value="'+selected+'"]').prop('disabled', true);

    }); 
   $(".loadgames").on('click',function()
    {
        var num = $("#s_cnt").val();
        $("#STable tr").slice(2).remove();
        for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++) 
        {
                var data = "<tr><td><select name='Game_id[]' class='Game'><option value='null'>Games</option><?php foreach ($data as $row){echo "<option value=".$row['di'] . ">" .$row['di']. "</option>";}?></select></td></tr>";
                $("#STable").append(data);
        }
        });  
   </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
var val = $(this).val();
var selected = $(this);
 $('select').nextAll('select').find('option').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('value')==val) {
     $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
 })
});
```

see the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/smLbv5od/21/).

Comment: With this code also its disabling only the first chosen option. Whereas I want to disable every option that I select.

Comment: you want all the options to be disabled which are selected in previous dropdowns?

Comment: I want to disable the variable (selected in first list  ) in second list and in thrid list both should be disabled (selected in first and second), and so on.I home I am making myself clear.

Comment: Yes I tried it, its not working as required. Even If you will check the demo, its disabling the first choice in second list, but in third list only second choice is disabled.whereas I am expecting both first and second one diable in third list.

Comment: i have not updated the link try with the code i have given above.

Comment: I dont have idea about how to create demo, though I have added the code in question.

Comment: @ Prasanna Venkatesh thanks. but which library you are talking about ...

Comment: you have to jquery library in order use jquery jsfiddle fiddle does not include any libraries you have to add one from settings icon in javascript tab.If working accept my answer

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('change', '.Game', function() {
        $('.Game option').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
     });      
  });
<script>

// For class
.Game option.active {opacity: 0.3;cursor: pointer}
```

Comment: I am new to the programming so not sure how we are going to add class.